# How can I allow html render in vue2, datatables Unescape html

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, datatables, vuejs2

#### update

ok. after a lot of searching Vue render is not my issue. dataTables server side convert escape html to like this

```
"image": "&lt;a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;media/test/img1.jpg&quot;&gt;show&lt;/a&gt;"
```

#### old problem!

I know about v-html, but my problem is when i want to render dynamic table (from dataTables).

http://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/.

How can i tell vue render html? Is there is some globaly option for do this?

My table :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" id="table_id" ></table>
```

my js:

```
self.dataTableSet = $('#table_id').on('preXhr.dt', function ( ) {
                self.$Progress.start();
            } ).DataTable({
                columns: columns,
                order: [[ count, 'desc' ]],
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    'type': 'get',
                    'url': axios.defaults.baseURL+"tests/get_data_table",
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'],'Authorization':this.$auth.getToken()},
                    data: function ( d ) {
                        d.advance_search = self.adv_search_form;
                       // d.from_date = sorting_from_date.val();
                    }

                },
                "drawCallback": function(  ) {
                    self.$Progress.finish();
                }
            });
```

Result 
[image: myresult]

Comment: I use the mounted method inside the vue to render Datatables

Comment: ok. after a lot of searching Vue render is not my issue. dataTables server side convert escape html to like this : "&lt;a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;media/test/img1.jpg&quot;&gt;show&lt;/a&g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and i find how to fix this.in my case:
laravel / config / dataTables.php  line 85:
change `'escape'    => '*',`
to `'escape'    => '',`

Answer (score 1):

In your created method on a component, you can use:

```
this.$options.template = someHtmlContent
```

And this will set the template of that component. With that in mind, you can create a component for Dynamic Html then pass the HTML as a prop then use that prop to set he `$options.template` as above.